# calling php function from html page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to call a simple php function (SetEligibleToEnrollTerms()) from an html page (dueligibletoenroll_view.php).  The path of this page is \cs\views\staff\advisees\dueligibletoenroll_view.php.

Below you can see I've tried a number of ways to call it starting at 'JEE19 begin'.

```
<?php 
$this->load->view('common/heading', array(
    'heading'       => 'Eligible to Enroll',
    'show_back_btn' => true
)) 

/*JEE19 begin*/
//use \cs\classes\CampusSolutions\API\Staff\Advisees\Advisees.php;
//include Advisees.php;
//require_once('Advisees.php');
/*JEE19 end*/
?>
<section>
...
...
                            <input style="margin-right:20px;" type="checkbox" data-role="none" data-message="<?php echo $message ?>" class="check-elig-enrl" id="<?php echo $term->acad_career . '/' . $term->acad_prog . '/' . $term->strm ?>" name="<?php echo $key ?>" value="<?php echo $term->acad_prog ?>" checked="checked" <?php echo $disabled ?>/>

<?php echo SetEligibleToEnrollTerms() ?>
```

The path of the script that has the function is cs\classes
CampusSolutions\API\Staff\Advisees.php

This is what the function does:

```
       public function SetEligibleToEnrollTerms() {
        echo "here3";
}
```

All of the different ways I've tried to call the function have resulted in errors similar to the one below describing how the code was unable to call it.  Does anyone know how I would call this function?

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function SetEligibleToEnrollTerms() in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 70
```

Comment: what is your class called?

Comment: class Advisees extends BaseClass {

Comment: Does this work? require_once('cs/classes/CampusSolutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php');

Comment: that gave me this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'require_once' (T_REQUIRE_ONCE) in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 15

Comment: you have a missing colon, bracket or something else before that line

Comment: What does `$this`refer to ?

Comment: this is at the top of the page:  <?php 
require_once('cs/classes/CampusSolutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php'); .....   and it gives me this error:   Message: require_once(cs/classes/CampusSolutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Have you just tried ` <?php require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cs/classes/CampusSolutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php'); ?>`

Comment: ya that loads successfully....now I'm just getting this error when I uncommented the function:   Fatal error: Call to undefined function seteligibletoenrollterms() in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 71

Comment: do i need to instantiate the class to call the function from it?

Comment: look at my answer ;) `$oAdvisees = new Advisees();

$oAdvisees->SetEligibleToEnrollTerms();`

Comment: ah ok...where would I put that code to instantiate it though?  would it go right where I call the php function?

Comment: after where its required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you init the class and call the method correctly?

```
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path_to_parent_class.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'path_to_class.php';

$oAdvisees = new Advisees();

$oAdvisees->SetEligibleToEnrollTerms();
```

Comment: would 'path_to_class.php' be cs\classes CampusSolutions\API\Staff\Advisees.php?

Comment: you can use  `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in the require path followed by the rest of the path, or echo it and use its value.

Comment: what would that look like?

Comment: updated answer, it may look like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cs/classes/CampusSoloutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php';`

Comment: that gave me this error:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$_SERVER' (T_VARIABLE) in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 16

Comment: Look above that line and find whatever isn't closed correctly

Comment: Looking at your code, try adding a semicolon to the end of: `$this->load->view('common/heading', array(
    'heading'       => 'Eligible to Enroll',
    'show_back_btn' => true
))`

Comment: ok we're getting close...now the page will load...one sec...let me add the function now

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function seteligibletoenrollterms() in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 71

Comment: have you typed the function name as lowercase? (Its case sensitive)

Comment: In the class it is SetEligibleToEnrollTerms.  Do I need to instantiate the class?

Comment: yes you will if its not already. Look at the last two lines on my answer

Comment: ok this is what I have at the top of the page:  <?php 
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/cs/classes/CampusSoloutions/API/Staff/Advisees.php';
$oAdvisees = new Advisees();
$oAdvisees->SetEligibleToEnrollTerms(); .......and it's giving me this error:  Fatal error: Call to undefined method Advisees::SetEligibleToEnrollTerms() in /srv/highpoint/cs/views/staff/advisees/dueligibletoenroll_view.php on line 11

Comment: if I comment out that line:  $oAdvisees->SetEligibleToEnrollTerms();   it loads....so it must be recognizing the class, but not the function right?

Comment: it's something with the path

Comment: is the method (function in the class) within the opening/closing braces of the class

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  I just added $advisees = new \CampusSolutions\API\Staff\Advisees();
            $e2eTerms = $advisees->SetEligibleToEnrollTerms();

Comment: You helped me a lot though - check mark for your services ;)